# How to read image file from S3 bucket directly into memory?

Tags: python, matplotlib, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('sentinel-s2-l1c')
object = bucket.Object('tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2')
object.download_file('B01.jp2')
img=mpimg.imread('B01.jp2')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show(imgplot)
```

and it works. But the problem it downloads file into current directory first. Is it possible to read file and decode it as image directly in RAM?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I would suggest using [io module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html) to read the file directly in to memory, without having to use a temporary file at all.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('sentinel-s2-l1c')
object = bucket.Object('tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2')

file_stream = io.StringIO()
object.download_fileobj(file_stream)
img = mpimg.imread(file_stream)
# whatever you need to do
```

You could also use `io.BytesIO` if your data is binary.

Comment: object.download_fileobj(file_stream)
gives me an error,
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'

Comment: I get the same error: TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Comment: If "string argument expected, got bytes" is your error, remember to try `io.BytesIO()` instead of `io.StringIO()`. For boto3 and python 3, that's the key

Comment: I am getting a `read past end of file` error when I am executing the last line of the code

Comment: @NeeleshkumarSrinivasanMannur I get the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any advice on how to clear out the image from memory, once uploaded?

For some reason, when iterated hundreds of times * numerous threads - the memory fills up :(

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 memory issues like that are always tricky. In general the python gc should be doing its job, so I'd make sure variables are properly scoped. You could also try an explicit `gc.collect()`, though I doubt that'd be helpful if the memory is truly never releasing.

Comment: You can use `del variable name` and python will delete it from memory

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838643/read-s3-file-into-a-buffer

Comment: How to download more than one band for a certain area using this code?

Answer (score 39):

Further development from Greg Merritt's answer to solve all errors in the comment section, using `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`, using PIL `Image` instead of `matplotlib.image`.

The following function works for `python3` and `boto3`. Similarly, `write_image_to_s3` function is a bonus.

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np

def read_image_from_s3(bucket, key, region_name='ap-southeast-1'):
    """Load image file from s3.

    Parameters
    ----------
    bucket: string
        Bucket name
    key : string
        Path in s3

    Returns
    -------
    np array
        Image array
    """
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    object = bucket.Object(key)
    response = object.get()
    file_stream = response['Body']
    im = Image.open(file_stream)
    return np.array(im)

def write_image_to_s3(img_array, bucket, key, region_name='ap-southeast-1'):
    """Write an image array into S3 bucket

    Parameters
    ----------
    bucket: string
        Bucket name
    key : string
        Path in s3

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name)
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    object = bucket.Object(key)
    file_stream = BytesIO()
    im = Image.fromarray(img_array)
    im.save(file_stream, format='jpeg')
    object.put(Body=file_stream.getvalue())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838643/read-s3-file-into-a-buffer Can you take a look here?

Answer (score 24):

### Greg Merritt's answer below is better method.

I'd like to suggest using Python's [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) in `tempfile` module. It creates temporary files that will be deleted as file is closed (Thanks to @NoamG)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import boto3
import tempfile

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('sentinel-s2-l1c')
object = bucket.Object('tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2')
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

with open(tmp.name, 'wb') as f:
    object.download_fileobj(f)
    img=mpimg.imread(tmp.name)
    # ...Do jobs using img
```

Comment: This should work fine, but under the hood, a real file is created and will be destroyed as soon as it is closed.

Comment: @NoamG Thanks! I was misunderstanding how `tempfile` module works. Updated my answers.

Comment: That a file is made at all even if temporarily is important for AWS Lambda users concerned about downloading files larger than 512 MB, since lambda limits users to 512 MB in /tmp

Answer (score 13):

Streaming the image is possible by specifying the file format in `imread()`.

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = resource.Bucket('sentinel-s2-l1c')

image_object = bucket.Object('tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2')
image = mpimg.imread(BytesIO(image_object.get()['Body'].read()), 'jp2')

plt.figure(0)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 10):

Slightly different approach using client:

```
import boto3
import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

client = boto3.client("s3")

bucket='my_bucket'
key= 'my_key'

outfile = io.BytesIO()
client.download_fileobj(bucket, key, outfile)
outfile.seek(0)
img = plt.imread(outfile)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This highlights the absolutely critical point - once the data have been downloaded to the buffer object, `seek()` back to `0` before onward processing!

Answer (score 5):

```
object = bucket.Object('tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2')
img_data = object.get().get('Body').read()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

The temporary file solution by Hyeungshik Jung looks good, but I noticed that the file somehow seem to be downloaded in a lazy fashion. This leads to a behavior that if you call `img.shape()` and you'll get an empty dimension tuple as a return value `()` even after you called `object.download_fileobj(f)`. I resolved this issue by applying a `f.seek(0,2)` to the file descriptor - then all following operations work properly, e.g. returning all proper dimensions `(704, 1024)`.

```
...
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

with open(tmp.name, 'wb') as f:
    object.download_fileobj(f)
    f.seek(0,2) 
    img=mpimg.imread(tmp.name)
    print (img.shape)
```

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of good answers here. Here is my code snippet with AWS Config if you quickly test out the solution. Please note that it's not recommended to put your AWS credentials in the code body, rather it should come from the .env file or from the AWS Keystore.

```
import os
import boto3
from PIL import Image
import io

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your-aws-access-key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your-aws-secret'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

def image_from_s3(bucket, key):
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    image = bucket.Object(key)
    img_data = image.get().get('Body').read()
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))

# call the function
image_from_s3("your-aws-bucket-name", "file-path")

# example
image_from_s3("my-images", "profile/2022/123.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you will read a byte type data from S3 but Tensorflow needs a string tensor to convert to uint8 image. And this method doesn't need Pillow.

```
import boto3
import tensorflow as tf

credentials = boto3.Session(botocore_session=boto3.setup_default_session(), 
                                region_name="us-east-1").get_credentials()
    

s3 = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key).client('s3') 

#file_on_s3 : 's3://mybucket/data/sample.jpg'
bucket_name = 'mybucket'
file_key = 'data/sample.jpg'


file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)

# reading the file content in bytes
file_content = file_obj["Body"].read()  


img =  tf.io.decode_image(tf.convert_to_tensor(file_content, dtype=tf.string), 
                                channels=3, 
                                dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, 
                                name=None, 
                                expand_animations=False)

img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
img_array = tf.image.resize(img, 
                            size=(224, 224),
                            method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pillow, ssl and urblib inn python3
from PIL import Image
import requests
import ssl
import urllib.request

```
img="https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{folder}/"
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
for i in range(1100,1102):
    image_url=img+str(i)+".png"
    im = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(image_url,context=context))
    im.show()`
```